# odoo[v8] rules for groups

Tags: security, odoo, rules

I have a boolean field 'classified' on sale order and my idea was that only users who are in the group that I created 'Classified quotations' can see records on tree view in which classified is true . I created two rules and I have no idea why it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
   <data>

      <record id="sale_order_rule_group_classified_quotations" model="ir.rule">
         <field name="name">sale_order_rule_group_classified_quotations</field>
         <field name="model_id" search="[('model','=','sale.order')]" model="ir.model"/>
            <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('group_classified_quotations'))]"/>
         <field name="domain_force">['|',('classified','=',True),('classified','=',False)]</field>
      </record>

         <record id="sale_order_rule_no_group" model="ir.rule">
         <field name="name">sale_order_rule_no_group</field>
         <field name="model_id" search="[('model','=','sale.order')]" model="ir.model"/>
            <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
         <field name="domain_force">[('classified','=',False)]</field>
      </record>

   </data>
</openerp>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell how it does not work (or how it behaves now). Also If you want to allow to see all records on rule, you should use this instead on `domain_force`: `[(1,'=',1)]`, this means all records and you don't need to make `True` or `False` checking. Try if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently done something similar but done so in the .py file.

You can do something like this:

```
    def write(self, cr, user, ids, vals, context=None):
        if vals.get('classified'):
            group_id = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, 1, 'your_model', 'your_group')
            user = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, user, user)
            if group_id not in user.groups_id:
                raise osv.except_osv(_('Error'), _("Only x user can adjust this field"))
    return super(your_model, self).write(cr, user, ids, vals, context=context)
```